# import javax.persistence.column, javax.persistence.entity, javax.persistence.Id - and so on - cannot be resolved

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, jpa, annotations

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring3-mvc-hibernate-maven-tutorial-eclipse-example/). Instead of starting by using the downloadable project I thought I'd start from a simple "spring MVC - Maven - eclipse" project I did before. This project was running fine.

So, as indicated in that tutorial, I started creating the packages. Then, I created my first class called `Contact.java` that contains various annotations. See the class below.

```
package sphbmveclp.contact.form;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="CONTACTS")
public class Contact {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name="LASTNAME")
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name="EMAIL")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="TELEPHONE")
    private String telephone;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public String getTelephone() {
        return telephone;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public void setTelephone(String telephone) {
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

I added the following dependency thinking it'd do the job as these annotations are "standard JPA annotations"

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

However, eclipse says

```
The import javax.persistence.Column cannot be resolved" for the first import.
The import javax.persistence.Entity cannot be resolved" for the second import.
```

and so on.

Here is the list of dependencies defined in my `pom.xml`:

```
  <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <javax.servlet.jstl.version>1.2</javax.servlet.jstl.version>
    </properties>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
       </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.servlet.jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

       <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>

       <dependency>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This fixed my issue:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Not exactly sure why I need it whereas it is not mentioned in the tutorial at all.